# How do I store search results in a react component for future use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, local-storage

I have a React app that uses Redux to manage state and React Router to navigate through different pages.

I have a page/component 'search by cocktail name' where you can search for a cocktail name in a cocktail API.
https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php.  So you search for, let's say 'Margarita' and you see the results on that same page.

Now, if you go to another page on my site then come back to the 'search by cocktail name' page, you no longer see the previous results of the previous 'Margarita' search.

I would like to still see the results of the previous 'Margarita' search when I go back to 'search by cocktail name' page/component.

Not sure how to do this.

Should I put the 'search input' (which is for now, just a state in the 'search by cocktail name' component, in a Redux slice and then redo search when you come back to page?  Should I instead just put the results of the search in Redux slice?

The thing is, I don't really need that piece of information outside of that 'search by cocktail name' component (which is usually the reason for using Redux).

Is there another way to do this?

Also, if I want to keep the results even if site is refreshed, I would necessarily need to store those values in localStorage?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: yeah localstorage is fine. don't overthink it, if it works its good

Answer (score 0):

In order to remember what the user entered, you can do 2 things:

1. Pass whatever the user is searching as a query parameter to the URL, and when the user loads the page, if anything is provided in the query parameter then you perform that search. If the user clicks on the back button now they will be redirected to the previous page which will have URL of the form: `example.com/search?query=Margharita` and they will be able to see the results
2. Since you are using react router, react router allows you to pass additional data (in json format) when you redirect to another page. So you could use that option to pass search results so that those results are reloaded if you come back to the page

Finally, yes if you want to persist data you need to use localStorage or sessionStorage. You can read on the differences of localStorage and sessionStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)